# How do I set up a controller, so that depending on which button is selected it will execute a specific command?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am quite new to coding and because this for work, I am not able to post my problem exactly. But I hope the below is sufficient to be steered in the right direction. 
I have created several buttons [btn1, btn2, btn3...] on the UI. Which needs to execute a similar command:

```
(
i.e. btn1 => restarts service_1
btn2 => restarts service_2
btn3 => restarts service_3
)
```

I have created a router and a controller that works when I click on btn1 (which executes cmd: restarts service_1). Instead of creating a different controller and router for each btn, I want to use only one (as the code for each button are almost identical). 
But I am struggling to work out how to code, so that depending on which button is pressed a particular command is executed. Would appreciate any help?

Many Thanks

Comment: Could you provide your current code ?

Answer (score 0):

With the few information you are providing, I will supose you are talking about HTML `button` and will try to give a general answer.

If you put your button in a form that triggers your controller, you can give them a name and a value.

For instance, with this code

```
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="foo" value="foo"/>
    <input type="submit" name="bar" value="bar"/>
    <input type="submit" name="tutu" value="tutu"/>
</form>
```

Your backend will get only the clicked button parameter.
If you click on `foo`, the backend gets `?foo=foo`, if you click on `bar`, the backends gets `?bar=bar`.
So you only have to check if the parameter exists or not to then proceed what you need to.

**EDIT**
To answer your comment here is something.

```js
$("form input[type=button]").click(function() {
  let val = $(this).val();
  let data = {value: val};
  console.log(val);
  
  $.ajax ({ 
    type: "POST", 
    url: "...",
    data: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="button" name="foo" value="foo"/>
  <input type="button" name="bar" value="bar"/>
  <input type="button" name="tutu" value="tutu"/>
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. that was really useful. How do I get the name into an function with an ajax call?
Example:
function callbtn (formName) {
$.ajax ({
type: "POST",
url: "<!--#include virtual...".../path/path"---->/btn_service/btn_name",
.....}))

How do I get the btn_name section to read the name of the form?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks again. Not sure if this is what I am looking for. If I wanted the name "Foo" to append to the URL. How do I extract this property from the form?

Comment: What do you mean "extract this property from the form" ?  

If you send the form with an `input type="submit"` the name and value will be append to the url as get parameters (or not if post) then send to the backend.  

Do you want to fetch the cliked value before sending the form to the backend ? If so just replace all the `button` by `submit` in the snippet. 
If not so, I don't understand what you are trying to do.